# Filling in 2d array with particular values

Tags: python, arrays

I would like to fill the fist column and first line in my 2D array, with the letters from string, as in example.
My code is filling as many rows as length given... Can you help me?

string1='polujsj'
string2='ksjuhjjj'

```
array:
  p o l u j s j
k 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
s 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
j 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
u 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
h 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
j 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
j 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
j 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

my code :

```
a=len(string1)
b=len(string2)
matrix= [ [ 0 for i in range(a+1) ] for j in range(b+1) ]
for n in range(0,a+1):
  for letters in string1:
    matrix[0][n]=letters

for rows in matrix:
  print rows
```

How can I achieve the effect above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
string1 = 'polujsj'
string2 = 'ksjuhjjj'
firstLine = list(' ' + string1)
matrix = [firstLine] + [[c] + [0] * len(string1) for c in string2]

for line in matrix:
    print(' '.join(map(str, line)))
```

It prints:

```
  p o l u j s j
k 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
s 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
j 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
u 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
h 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
j 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
j 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
j 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want a matrix of zeros.  You can build an output string:

```
string1='polujsj'
string2='ksjuhjjj'

a=len(string1)
b=len(string2)
matrix= [ [ 0 for i in range(a) ] for j in range(b) ]

out = '  '
for letter in string1:
    out += letter + ' '
for i in range(b):
    out += '\n' + string2[i] + ' '
    for item in matrix[i]:
        out += str(item) + ' '
print(out)
```